# Passing array of pointers to a function C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm passing an array of pointers to a function and modifying them but they are changing unexpectedly.
This is my main function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
   int x;
   int y; 
}enemy;

void main() {
  enemy* array[5];
  function(array);
}
```

And this is the function not working:

```
void function(enemy* arr[]){
   int b;
   for(b=0;b<5;b++)
      arr[b]=(enemy*)malloc(sizeof(enemy));
  for(b=0;b<5;b++){
      arr[b]->x=b;
      arr[b]->y=b*16;
      printf("%d %d, ", arr[0]->x, arr[0]->y);
  }
}
```

Every time I call `printf` the first pointer of the array changes its values and I don't know why.

The printf prints: "0 0, 1 16, 2 32, 3 48, 4 64". Shouldn't it prints all the time "0 0"? That's what I expected.

Comment: and what is `maxEnemigosSala` ?

Comment: how do you check the the value of array changed? show us your printf or whatever code too

Comment: @Alex: or maybe not. how should we know?

Comment: Have you used a debugger or valgrind (if on Linux) to help you find the problem? Either of those could save you hours of just staring at the code.

Comment: `b` is undefined, too...

Comment: I added the printf to the original post. I can't debug because I'm developing for Amstrad CPC and the debuger works in assembler which I don't domine.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, I forgot to write it here, but It is in the original code.

Comment: i think you need to use a debugger. it's hard to determine with your incomplete code.

Comment: try to have `cordx = cordy = cont` see what happens

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Well just tell me which part of the code you need :)

Comment: What does `cpct_getRandomUniform_u8_f` do? Any chance of memory corruption in that function? And if you can't use a debugger then add more `printf` statements in. After every line if you have to :-)

Comment: @kaylum this it     cpct_getRandomUniform_u8_f http://lronaldo.github.io/cpctelera/files/random/cpct_getRandomUniform_u8_f-s.html

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forget to answer the question. But with **sufficient information** I could probably answer it within a minute or so.

Comment: @wildplasser Well I tought this code was enought information. I'm sorry. Just tell me what else you need :)

Comment: @Alex The problem is we can't really tell you what we need. Because we don't know what your *real code* is doing. So there could be a problem in some part of the code that is not shown. If that is the case then it is impossible for anyone (without mind reading abilities) to ask for that unknown information. What you really need to provide is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, there is for instance, a difference of `maxEnemigosSala` being a #deined constant, or a variable (a variable can be overwritten, a minifest constant cannot). BTW: main() shall return int.

Comment: in C, when calling malloc() and family of functions, the returned value is a `void *` which can be assigned to any other pointer, so no need to cast the returned value.   casting the returned value just clutters the code and leads to headaches when performing maintenance.

Comment: when declaring the `main()` function,  there are only a very small number of ways to declare it.  And all those ways have the return type as 'int'.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks, I fixed that but It didn't solve the problem

Comment: The function: `function()` is not prototyped, so *earlier compilers will make assumptions* modern compilers will issue a warning. or even a error message.    When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.   (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: when calling `mallic()` or `calloc()` or `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding these two line:  `arr[b]->x=b;
      arr[b]->y=b*16;`   lets remember that arr[b] is, itself, a pointer.  therefore the code needs to dereference that pointer.  What it is currently doing is changing that pointer.  suggest: `(*arr[b])->x=b;
      (*arr[b])->y=b*16;`   and remember operator precedence, so place the pointer in parens

Comment: @user3629249 I tried to dereference the pointer with the code you provided but the compiler says "Error 27: Pointer required"

Comment: your right, my oops,. sorry

Comment: @alex I have a feeling there is something specific to your system. I can't reproduce your problem on my system and from the other comments/answers it looks like others can't either. And [here is another system](https://ideone.com/21dPb8) showing the result of your code and it also does not exhibit the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is the verison of your code that I used for testing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
   int x;
   int y;
}enemy;

void function(enemy* arr[]);

int main( void )
{
  enemy* array[5];
  function(array);
}

void function(enemy* arr[])
{
   int b;
   for(b=0;b<5;b++)
      arr[b]=(enemy*)malloc(sizeof(enemy));
  for(b=0;b<5;b++){
      arr[b]->x=b;
      arr[b]->y=b*16;
      printf("%d %d, ", arr[0]->x, arr[0]->y);
  }
}
```

Note: the final printf() is always outputting the first entry in the array

The result is:

```
0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0,
```

what did I change?

```
1) corrected the return type from main()
2) prototyped the `function()` function.
```

Comment: I just copied the code from the answer, compiled it, ran it all on ubuntu linux 14.04.  compiled with: `gcc -c -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std-c99 code.c -o code.o`   then `gcc -ggdb code.o -o code`  then ran it with `./code` and it gave the correct output of: `0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, `  What did you do different?

Comment: since it actually works, how about bumping the 'score' to remove the -1

Answer (score 0):

*Every* time you call function?  Do you mean you're calling it more than once?

If so, function is replacing all pointers within arr on every call.  Move the malloc loop to main, then call function as you'd like

Comment: I'm sorry I wanted to say every time I call printf

Comment: @Alex I downloaded your code, built it [with -Wall and with/without -O2] and ran it.  I'm _unable_ to reproduce your problem.  I even had the printf dump arr[0] and arr[b] x/y pairs--all is fine.  I've examined the code and it appears to be fine.  Are you doing any exotic compile options?

Comment: Well thanks anyway. Maybe its something related to the machine I'm developing for.

Comment: @Alex Try some variations.  Take the stack based array defined in main and make it a global.  Also, under gdb, does your arch support the watch command?  If it does, that would definitely nail it.  Stylistically, you've hardwired 5 in all your loops and the array def.  If you're careful, that's fine.  But, for me, I'd do "#define ARRAYLEN 5" and replace all hardwired 5's with ARRAYLEN's so that you guarantee matchup of definitions and loop code